# ng build command not working in jenkins pipeline

Tags: angular, jenkins

I'm fairly new to Jenkins. I set up a pipeline in Jenkins for an Angular 7 app. Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        echo 'Checkout master branch'
        checkout scm
        dir('webapp') {
          bat 'npm install'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo 'Building..'
        dir('webapp') {
          bat 'npm run ng -- build --prod --baseHref=/webapp/ -optimization=true'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        echo 'Deploying....'
        ftpPublisher paramPublish: null, masterNodeName: '', alwaysPublishFromMaster: true, continueOnError: false, failOnError: true, publishers: [
          [configName: 'mattdailey.net', verbose: true, transfers: [
            [asciiMode: false, cleanRemote: true, excludes: '', flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: tur, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+',
              remoteDirectory: "webapp", removePrefix: "webapp/dist", remoteDirectorySDF: false, sourceFiles: 'webapp/dist/**'
            ]
          ], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    success {
      slackSend(color: '#00FF00', message: "Build Successful")
    }
    failure {
      slackSend(color: '#FF0000', message: "Build Failed")
    }
  }
}
```

When I create a build I get the following error:

```
ng "build" "--prod" "--baseHref=/webapp/" "-optimization=true"

Unknown option: '-n'    
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE    
npm ERR! errno 1
```

I'm using Jenkins 2.150.3, Angular CLI 7.3.4, NodeJS 10.15.1 in Windows 10. If I take out the '--' between ng and build the command works but it ignores the flags after a build. I think I need to add a path variable for angular cli but I'm not sure where to add it or what the right syntax would be.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the issue but what I see is `-optimization=true` instead of `--optimization=true`. So I would remove the double hyphens between `ng` and `build` fix the optimization flag then run it again.

Comment: when you say `the build command works`, what do you mean? It builds, but it doesn't serve up the content via your web server? Or it builds and serves via web server?

Comment: Please share your latest .gitlab-ci.yml file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andrew Lobban Fixing the optimization flag helped. I did have to keep the '--' between ng and build, otherwise it wouldn't recognize any of the flags. When I said it works I meant angular cli would do a regular build without any flags. Thanks.

Comment: The only issue I have left is when the files get deployed to the site using Publish Over FTP it doesn't transfer an assets subfolder. It transfers all the files except for this particular subfolder.

Comment: What sort of error output, if any would you get if you simply did `ng build --prod --baseHref=/webapp/ --optimization=true` removing the `npm run`?

Comment: I would get something along the lines of 'ng' isn't recognized as a command.

Comment: @mdailey77 It was not clear how you solved the reported problem...?????

Comment: I fixed the problem by fixing the syntax. For instance changing `-optimization=true to --optimization=true`

Answer (score 2):

The same problem I faced with Octopus CICD build. Below solution works for me.

1. Change in package json script like `"build": "ng build --prod",`
2. Run command from CICD like `npm run build`

Hope it help !